# how to run python function again and again and never stop unless I stop it?

Tags: python

I am currently writing a python script. As I want it to check an API data in real time, so I want it to call the API function every 1 second. How should I done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
import time
while True:
    call_api()
    time.sleep(1)
```

here `call_api` will be called until you stop the program by `ctrl+c`

Comment: note that is will run *forever*. OP should know that the only way to exit this is to: `break`, `ctrl + c` or kill the Python instance

Comment: And of cause it's `True` instead of `true`.